# Weird JavaScript behaviour with variable/alert

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get some variable from a html form. I can read all of the values except for one, on which I do absolutely nothing different.

I tried to  `console.log` `starttijd`, it shows nothing in my console.
But when I `alert` `starttijd` it does show me the right value. This is the code I'm running:

```js
function validateGroepslesForm() {

  var message = "";
  var date = document.forms["groepslesform"]["date"].value;
  if (!date) {
    message += "Vul een geldige datum in<br>";
  }

  var endtime = document.forms["groepslesform"]["endtime"].value;
  if (endtime == "") {
    message += "Vul een geldige eindtijd in<br>";
  }

  var starttijd = document.forms["groepslesform"]["starttime"].value;
  if (starttijd = "") {
    message += "Vul een geldige starttijd in<br>";
  }
  console.log(starttijd);

  var participants = document.forms["groepslesform"]["participants"].value;
  if (participants == "0") {
    message += "Vul een geldig aantal deelnemers in<br>";
  }
```

```html
<p>Datum:</p>
<input type="date" name="date" id="futuredate" value="" />
<p>Start tijd:</p>
<input type="text" name="starttime" id="starttime" placeholder="Start tijd van de groepsles" value="" />
<p>Eind tijd:</p>
<input type="text" name="endtime" id="endtime" placeholder="Eind tijd van de groepsles" value="" />
<p>Maximaal aantal deelnmers</p>
<input type="number" name="participants" id="participants" min="0" value="16" />
```

Comment: `if (starttijd= "") {` will always be true... It is assignment, not comparison....

Comment: You missed a `=` there !

Comment: Oh wow, Is there a close vote for being embarrassed

Comment: In the snippet you have posted, there is also a } missing at the end. Besides, the form is not defined in the html.

Comment: @jrook yeah I know, I thought I would just post the (somewhat) relevant code, there are 5/6 more values in the form/javascript

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison check is assignment in the code.
Change to:

```
if (starttijd == "") {
    message+= "Vul een geldige starttijd in <br>";
}
```

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: I write answer and add the description and you were fast to comment before. :D

Comment: I commented on the answer you posted. Perhaps you shouldn't have clicked "Post Your Answer" before you had finished writing it.